# Reference path not capturing interface using import - IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, types, import

**File Structure**

```
frontend
  | static
    | ts
      | react
        |components
          AnotherFile.d.ts
          Index.d.ts
```

**Context**

When I implement *AnotherFile.d.ts* and *Index.d.ts* as follows, IntelliJ doesn't seem to produce any errors regarding these two files:

*Index.d.ts*

```
interface myFuncType {
  (n: number): void;
}
```

*AnotherFile.d.ts*

```
/// <reference path='./Index.d.ts'/>
interface AnotherType {
  f: myFuncType
}
```

---

Now, if *Index.d.ts* imports and uses a class as follows, IntelliJ red-underlines 'myFuncType' in *AnotherFile.d.ts* with the error, `TS2304: Cannot find name 'myFuncType'`.

*Index.d.ts*

```
import {MyClass} from "static/ts/MyClass";

interface myFuncType {
  (n: MyClass) : void;
}
```

*AnotherFile.d.ts*

```
/// <reference path='./Index.d.ts'/>
interface AnotherType {
  f: myFuncType;
}
```

**Notes**

1. If I replace the `...<reference path.../>` line in the second case for *AnotherFile.d.ts* to `import {myFuncType} from "static/ts/react/components/Index";`, the error goes away, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make this work while using `...<reference path.../>`.
2. Marking *frontEnd* as 'Resources Root' seems to be the difference between allowing using relative paths in `import ...` lines (e.g. `import {myFuncType} from "./Index"` instead of `import {myFuncType} from "static/ts/react/components/Index";`

**Question**

How can I get the second case to work without introducing any "import" statement in *AnotherFile.d.ts*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `import` to your `Index.d.ts` you make it a [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). Unlike [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html), modules can only be consumed by importing them explicitly using one of the import forms - thus the compiler error.

When defining your interface (what `d.ts` files are supposed to be used for), you need to decide what kind of application you are working on. If it's a modular application, you need using modules. For global app that is supposed to be accessed from global scope (via `<script src=...>` in browser, for example), use namespaces. Mixing both in same code won't work.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html for more info